# broadcasting linalg.pinv on a 3D theano tensor

Tags: python, linear-algebra, theano, matrix-inverse

in the example below, there is a 3d numpy matrix of size (4, 3, 3)+ a solution about how to calculate pinv of each of 4 of those 3*3 matrices in numpy. I also tried to use the same function worked in numpy, in theano hoping that it is implemented the same, but it failed. Any idea how to do it in theano?

```
dt = np.dtype(np.float32)

a=[[[12,3,1],
   [2,4,1],
   [2,4,2],],
   [[12,3,3],
   [2,4,4],
   [2,4,5],],
   [[12,3,6],
   [2,4,5],
   [2,4,4],],
   [[12,3,3],
   [2,4,5],
   [2,4,6]]]

a=np.asarray(a,dtype=dt)
print(a.shape)

apinv=np.zeros((4,3,3))
print(np.linalg.pinv(a[0,:,:]).shape)

#numpy solution
apinv = map(lambda n: np.linalg.pinv(n), a)
apinv = np.asarray(apinv,dtype=dt)

#theano solution (not working)
at=T.tensor3('a')
apinvt = map(lambda n: T.nlinalg.pinv(n), at)
```

The error is:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydevd.py", line 2403, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "pydevd.py", line 1794, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "exp_thn_pinv_map.py", line 35, in <module>
    apinvt = map(lambda n: T.nlinalg.pinv(n), at)
  File "theano/tensor/var.py", line 549, in __iter__
    raise TypeError(('TensorType does not support iteration. '
TypeError: TensorType does not support iteration. Maybe you are using builtin.sum instead of theano.tensor.sum? (Maybe .max?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/source/intro_theano/pinv.py", line 32, in <module>
    apinvt = map(lambda n: T.nlinalg.pinv(n), at)
  File "d:\dropbox\source\theano\theano\tensor\var.py", line 549, in __iter__
    raise TypeError(('TensorType does not support iteration. '
TypeError: TensorType does not support iteration. Maybe you are using builtin.sum instead of theano.tensor.sum? (Maybe .max?)
```

This is occurring because, as the error message indicates, the symbolic variable `at` is not iterable.

The fundamental problem here is that you're incorrectly mixing immediately executed Python code with delayed execution Theano symbolic code.

You need to use a symbolic loop, not a Python loop. The correct solution is to use Theano's `scan` operator:

```
at=T.tensor3('a')
apinvt, _ = theano.scan(lambda n: T.nlinalg.pinv(n), at, strict=True)
f = theano.function([at], apinvt)
print np.allclose(f(a), apinv)
```

Comment: great, thank you for the help and the suggestion about the question. need to get my head around the scan function though.